# mysql select id not in

Tags: mysql, sql

Table `industrial_division`

```
| industrial_division_id |
| ---------------------- |
| 1                      |
| 2                      |
| 3                      |
| 4                      |
| 5                      |
| 6                      |
```

Table `members`

```
| member_id | industrial_division_id |
| --------- | ---------------------- |
| 19961     | 1                      |
| 21381     | 3                      |
| 21582     | 4                      |
| 21947     | 3                      |
| 24466     | 5                      |
| 29168     | 1                      |
| 29184     | 1                      |
| 29218     | 1                      |
```

Table `products`

```
| product_id |
| ---------- |
| 2177       |
| 2196       |
| 2234       |
| 2356       |
| 2523       |
| 2779       |
```

Table `industrial_division_product`

```
| ID   | industrial_division_id | product_id |
| ---- | ---------------------- | ---------- |
| 2282 | 6                      | 2177       |
| 2301 | 6                      | 2196       |
| 2339 | 1                      | 2234       |
| 2461 | 5                      | 2356       |
| 3018 | 1                      | 2356       |
| 2628 | 6                      | 2523       |
| 2884 | 1                      | 2779       |
```

Table `product_member`

```
| product_member_id | product_id | member_id |
| ----------------- | ---------- | --------- |
| 21997             | 2423       | 19961     |
| 21998             | 2424       | 19961     |
| 21999             | 2425       | 19961     |
| 22000             | 2426       | 19961     |
| 22001             | 2427       | 19961     |
| 22002             | 2356       | 19961     |
| 24504             | 2196       | 21381     |
| 24748             | 2205       | 21582     |
| 24749             | 2523       | 21582     |
| 25116             | 2177       | 21947     |
| 28485             | 2356       | 24466     |
| 34257             | 2234       | 29168     |
| 34271             | 2779       | 29184     |
| 34298             | 2779       | 29218     |
```

i want to make sql appear the members who have products and product's division not in the same division for members i tried this sql but the member `19961` appear

> the member `19961` locate in division (1) and he has product `2356` locate in two division (5,1)

```sql
SELECT
    product_member.product_member_id,
    product_member.member_id,
    product_member.product_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(industrial_division_product.industrial_division_id) as product_division,
    members.industrial_division_id as member_division

FROM
    product_member

JOIN members ON members.member_id = product_member.member_id
JOIN industrial_division_product ON industrial_division_product.product_id = product_member.product_id
WHERE industrial_division_product.industrial_division_id != members.industrial_division_id
GROUP BY product_member.product_member_id
```

```
| product_member_id | member_id | product_id | product_division | member_division |
| ----------------- | --------- | ---------- | ---------------- | --------------- |
| 22002             | 19961     | 2356       | 5                | 1               |
| 24504             | 21381     | 2196       | 6                | 3               |
| 24749             | 21582     | 2523       | 6                | 4               |
| 25116             | 21947     | 2177       | 6                | 3               |
| 28485             | 24466     | 2356       | 1                | 5               |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a basic `JOIN` query with aggregation -- but the aggregation should be at the right level, which I think is the member/product level.  Then you can use a `having` clause for the filtering rather than a `where` clause:

```
select pm.product_member_id as product_member_id, m.member_id,
       p.product_id, 
       group_concat(idp.industrial_division_id) as product_divisions,
       m.member_division as industrial_division_id
from product_member pm join
     members m
     on pm.member_id = m.member_id join
     industrial_division_product idp
     on ipd.product_id = pm.product_id
group by pm.product_member_id, m.member_division, p.product_id, m.member_id
having sum(m.industrial_division_id = idp.industrial_division_id) = 0;
```

The `sum()` is counting the number of product divisions that match the member divisions.  Because there can be multiple product divisions, you want only rows where none match.

The `sum()` itself is using a MySQL short-cut.  In other databases, it might be written as:

```
sum(case when m.industrial_division_id = idp.industrial_division_id then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```